# Jquery Mobile Swipe issue - Is there any fix

Tags: jquery-mobile

Swiping is not working properly when we use Jquery Mobile on Android devices. Swiping is not smooth or sometimes it does not work at all.

```js
$(document).off('swipeleft swiperight','.test')
    .on('swipeleft swiperight','.test', function(event) {       
        swipe(event);
});
```

`.test` - refers to a div class.

Please help. And, what is the problem in JQM, even it is not working on Samsung galaxy S4 native browser. Is there any easy way to achieve this without using any new plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

set it **to default**

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
   // settings
   $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
   $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
});
```

and then try this:

```
$('div').on('swipeleft', function(e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.Can you please explain what the above code does. I have set defaultPageTransition to "none" in my code. Moreover, this is a swipe of a section within a page and not a full page swipe.

Comment: Tested this. Swiping sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. Looks like it works based on some angle of touch.

Comment: Stop's JQM to style the page... sry that wasn't asked...  the mobile init function will be called at the mobile initalization of the page. Have you added all scripts?

Comment: Yes i have added all that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153090/jquery-mobile-swipe-event-on-android-emulator-works-only-sometimes-using-phoneg      look at this